# Seeing your Stack Overflow history

Tags: discussion, history

It might be the early dementia but I probably read about a dozen Stack Overflow articles a day and seem to have issues trying to get back to an article I read three articles ago if I've closed the browser or otherwise lost the train. Plus I wouldn't mind seeing what the elite on this site are reading so wasn't sure if this existed or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can check your own history by using the History feature of your browser. While not all browsers are equally user friendly in this aspect, some browsers like Firefox allow you to search your history. For me, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> followed by <kbd>stack</kbd> gives me a list of mostly Stack Overflow pages I've visited.

You cannot see the history of others, and I don't think you should be able to. Privacy and all that.

Comment: Thanks man, At last I found my history (it's been a dream)

Comment: The question is about SO history, not browser history.

Answer (score 3):

Short of writing your own [front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJClV.jpg) to Stack Overflow which some of us have and might release to [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/), yes, use browser history.

The problem with browser history is that it jumps around. For instance with Chrome, if you are at page 3 of browser history, it might just refresh to page 1 on a whim when you finally navigate to around where you think your prior view happened. Not to mention that it removes that link at that timeline when you do revisit.

That plus about a 100 built in queries prompted us to re-work an interface that dealt with a lot of short-comings to the GUI 99.9% of people use for Stack Overflow. Mainly, how to get at information quickly. How to Team Batch (bn), Earmark (em) and determine if you have Seen (sn) before (those columns in the first link above. Then publish this info for other's [consumption](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33878601#33878601).

Your issue was one of them. How to get at prior stuff when you knew you saw it about [12 hours ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so8lB.jpg) and wanted to get to it simply, chronologically, (with a GUI screen) or share that info with team-mates.

You need a database for this. For teams, it needs to be in the Cloud.

Comment: What's the first screenshot from?

Comment: A c# app that is a GUI front-end to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Looks interesting. I look forward to seeing if it ends up on StackApps

Comment: I'm particularly interested in that AutoPilot checkbox :)

Comment: What, and not the Tomfoolery tab in the lower right? :p ... The AutoPilot scans thru question history. The main columns of interest for moderation are cv (close votes), dv (delete votes), rv (reopen votes), vo (net votes) . And the ign (Ignore) is nice on certain views to ignore questions you don't want to see again. That sort of stuff. Oh, and the rep (Reputation) allows you to set a certain minimum rep as a filter.